# Does a ring homomorphism necessarily induce a map of their spectrums?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

As the text states, it is true.[image]
However, the map
$$\varphi:\mathbb Z \to \mathbb Z^2, n \mapsto (n, 0)$$
seems to be a counter example as $\varphi^{-1}(\mathbb Z\times\{0\})=\mathbb Z$.

Comment: That's not a ring homomorphism (at least according to the usual definition) as it does not send $1_{\Bbb Z}$ to $1_{\Bbb Z^2}$.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Thank U. I did have some misunderstanding of the def of ring homomorphisms.

Comment: Check with the text, but it probably contains the statement that rings are unital and ring homomorphisms preserve the identity. If it doesn't, then pretend it does, because your remarks shows that preservation of identity is necessary for defining the Spec functor.

Comment: @egreg Yes, it contains the statement. Thank you.